# IE 11 positioning issue versus Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html, css-position

I have been the following code that is not properly positioning itself when reviewed on Firefox against IE 11:

```
<div style="position: absolute;">    
<div style="position: relative; top: 5px; left: 30px;">Union Affiliation:</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: 50px; left: 30px;">Biography:</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: 150px; left: 30px;">Past Works:</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: 209px; left: 30px;">Primary Work Area:</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: 225px; left: 30px;">Miles willing to travel for work:</div>
</div>
```

I have tried a handful of adjustments, but nothing is lining it up right.  From what I can tell with IE 11 we should be able to avoid having to detect that internet explorer is in use.  If so, how can I get these elements to be consistently laid out across the browsers?

---

Here are screenshots to see the variation...

First FF:

[image]

Second IE:

[image]

Comment: *"I have tried a handful of adjustments, but nothing is lining it up right."* In ***what way*** is it wrong? *"If so, how can I get these elements to be consistently laid out across the browsers?"* Consistently ***how***? How is it inconsistent in IE11?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a valid DOCTYPE specified? e.g. is your first line `<!doctype html>` or similar?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Primary Work Area:` and `Miles willing to travel for work:` show up about 30 px below where they show up on FF

Comment: @scunliffe the first line showing up in source is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added screenshots to help view the variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you why you're not getting the results you want, but with the question as it is now, I can't tell you how to get the results you *do* want.

`position: relative` combined with `left` and `top` means that you're offsetting the element from where it *would be* in the browser's default layout. So you're still completely subject to how the browser lays the elements out relative to other elements, you're just moving them a bit based on that location.

If you want the labels to be aligned in some way with the inputs on the right, you need to put them both in some container (a `div`, for instance) and if necessary adjust them *within* that container. (To do that, you probably have to make the container `position: relative` without any `left` or `top`, so that it's the offset parent for its children.) By putting both within the same container, you ensure they're working from a similar basic position (the container).

Comment: An addendum to that last paragraph: A common practice on my end is to have one or more container `div`s that set `position: relative` with NO top/left attributes - then, sub-elements with `position: absolute` will position themselves based on the position of that parent. You could do this for each of those input fields.

Comment: @Katana314: Good point, I should have called that out. (And now I have.)