# SVG positioning:relative broken in just IE on my site?

Tags: svg

I apologise if this question has been asked various times before, but I haven't been able to find a clear or simple answer in the last few hours.

I run a clinical exams site, for which I've recently created a small SVG logo, as can be seen in the navigation bar here: https://simpleosce.com/

The code in my html document is as follows. This SVG is just wrapped by an anchor tag:

```
<a href="https://www.SimpleOSCE.com"><svg class="theLogo" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22.38 25"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#009955;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cls-1" d="M22.32,7.43a2.49,2.49,0,0,0-1.26-2.15L12.36.33a2.49,2.49,0,0,0-2.49,0L1.23,5.4A2.49,2.49,0,0,0,0,7.57l.06,10a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,1.26,2.15L10,24.67a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,2.49,0l8.63-5.06a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,1.23-2.17Zm-3.69,5.7A1.85,1.85,0,0,1,16.78,15H13.67v3.11a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85,1.85H10.56a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85-1.85V15H5.6a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85-1.85V11.87A1.85,1.85,0,0,1,5.6,10H8.71V6.91a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85-1.85h1.26a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85,1.85V10h3.11a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85,1.85Z" transform="translate(0)"/></svg></a>
```

This is all next to a header tag with the site name. I'm positioning the SVG above with class "theLogo" like so:

```
.theLogo{height:24px; position:relative; margin: 12px 0px 0px -5px;}
```

Which displays fine on chrome, firefox and edge. Looks really wrong in IE. 
Is there a way I can make this behave as expected?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436566/ie-11-positioning-issue-versus-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio` to the svg file, then by default `preserveAspectRatio = "xMidYMid meet"`

This is one of the possible reasons why the logo in IE11 takes place in the middle of the block and breaks the layout

### IE11

[image]

Try adding  `preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin meet"` and viewport -  `width ="22.38" height="25"`

```css
.theLogo{height:24px; position:relative; margin: 12px 0px 0px -5px;}
 .nav-brand{float:left;margin:0;}
.nav-brand a{display:block;padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;color:black;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:29px;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<h2 class="nav-brand"><a href="https://www.SimpleOSCE.com">SimpleOSCE</a></h2>
 <a href="https://www.SimpleOSCE.com"><svg class="theLogo" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width ="22.38" height="25" viewBox="0 0 22.38 25" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#009955;}
 </style>
 </defs>
 <title>Untitled-5</title>
 <path class="cls-1" d="M22.32,7.43a2.49,2.49,0,0,0-1.26-2.15L12.36.33a2.49,2.49,0,0,0-2.49,0L1.23,5.4A2.49,2.49,0,0,0,0,7.57l.06,10a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,1.26,2.15L10,24.67a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,2.49,0l8.63-5.06a2.49,2.49,0,0,0,1.23-2.17Zm-3.69,5.7A1.85,1.85,0,0,1,16.78,15H13.67v3.11a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85,1.85H10.56a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85-1.85V15H5.6a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.85-1.85V11.87A1.85,1.85,0,0,1,5.6,10H8.71V6.91a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85-1.85h1.26a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85,1.85V10h3.11a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,1.85,1.85Z" transform="translate(0)"/></svg></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly and acts as expected on IE. Many thanks for your time!!